# C# Automapper conditional mapping of child properties

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, mapping, automapper

I know, there are tons of questions related to this topic, but I couldn't find an answer to what I was looking for. All the questions seem to be related to the top level properties, and what I'm looking for is a conditional mapping for child properties.

In the [official documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html) itself, there's no such example either, unfortunately.
Here's an example that they have:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
cfg.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.baz, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.baz >= 0)));
});
```

In my case, I want something like this:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
cfg.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.baz.foo, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.baz.foo >= 0)));
});
```

But this is ofc throwing an exception, because you can't use "ForMember" for child properties. Instead you need to use "ForPath". What I'd expect, is to have similar code, that will work just fine for the child properties the following way:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
cfg.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
  .ForPath(dest => dest.baz.foo, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.baz.foo >= 0)));
});
```

But this code won't even compile, since the signature differes for the "Condition" method in "ForPath". So I've adjusted it to based on what the signature wanted and added "Source", before accessing the property, the following way:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
cfg.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
  .ForPath(dest => dest.baz.foo, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.Source.baz.foo >= 0)));
});
```

And even though the code complies and looks okay to me, the conditional mapping does not work. It's being ignored and the property is being set all the time, no matter what the value of "foo" is.

**I have ended up with a working code, though. I took an alternative path to get what I need, using "AfterMap" method:**

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
cfg.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
  .ForPath(dest => dest.baz, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (src.Source.baz)))
  .AfterMap((dest, src) => 
  {
     // Resetting the value of the property I don't need based on the reversed condition
     if (src.baz.foo < 0)
     {
        src.baz.foo = default;
     }
  }
});
```

**Even though I got it working, I want to know how to achieve the same result with conditional mapping? And what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Can you please try below. It works for me 
.ForMember(x => x.TestId, x => {
   x.PreCondition(m => m.TData.TestId is { Value: { } });
    x.MapFrom(m => m.TData.TestId);
 });

Note that above code ensure TestId is a GUID

Comment: Hey, @Chandana, thanks for your comment. Your code may work, however it's not a mapping for a child property at destination. For nested child properties, you can't use "ForMember" method.

Comment: You don't need the `Condition`, just write all the code inside your `MapFrom`.

Comment: Thanks, @LucianBargaoanu, haven't thought of that one.